# Too large executable size when using wxDev-C++ with GCC or MSVC Compiler

Tags: gcc, wxwidgets, exe, visual-studio-2010, code-size

I'm creating a simple (hello world!) C++ application with a very simple GUI (only a frame with no element) using wxDev-C++ IDE (in windows 7).
The problem is that size of output .exe file is too big (about 2MB when I compile using MSVC10 compiler & more that 8MB when I use GCC compile & these sizes are best cases!).
I've checked many possibilities (such as excluding debug information or optimizing for size), but non of them does not help for reducing executable size.
I strongly guess there is a linkage problem, because I've seen a [demo application](ftp://biolpc22.york.ac.uk/pub/binary/wxWidgets-WidgetsDemo-Windows.zip) that contains almost all of widgets with only about 1MB of code size.
Any idea?

Comment: Static or dynamic linking?

Answer (score 1):

Here are the steps you need to follow to reduce the size of statically linked wxWidgets applications using mingw :

1.Compile the library with the following options :

> -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -Os

This will place each function or data item into its own section.

2.Link the executable to the library with the following options :

> -Wl,--gc-sections -s

Symbols and unused function and data sections will be removed.

With these options the produced executable size will be about 3.3 MB. Of course, this means that you have to compile the library yourself instead of using prebuilt binaries. I had used the following bat file to compile the library:

```
cd C:\wxWidgets\build\msw
mingw32-make SHELL=CMD.exe -j4 -f makefile.gcc BUILD=release UNICODE=1 SHARED=0 clean
mingw32-make SHELL=CMD.exe -j4 -f makefile.gcc CPPFLAGS="-MD -MP -DHAVE_W32API_H -D__WXMSW__ -DNOPCH -DwxDEBUG_LEVEL=0 -DNDEBUG" CFLAGS="-mthreads -pipe -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-builtin -Os" CXXFLAGS="-mthreads -Wno-ctor-dtor-privacy -pipe -fmessage-length=0 -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -fno-builtin -Os" LDFLAGS="-Wl,--subsystem,windows -Wl,--gc-sections -s -mthreads -mwindows" BUILD=release UNICODE=1 SHARED=0
```

Also I recommend that you use code::block or Qt Creator instead of wxDev. I personally use Qt Creator. It has a great editor and QMake makes things easier.

Answer (score 0):

What did you expect when you pack the entire contents into one exe file? (Static)

The size of the compiled .exe file based on many factors. But if you compile it as static, you create by far the largest.

Here is for example a wxWidgets Application. Compiled two times. One with VC2010 and the second with minGW.

[image]

Compiled Dynamic with VS2010 WinXP 127.488 KB

[image]

Compiled Dynamic with MinGW gcc WinXP 1.018.639 KB

[image]

you wrote:
`about 2MB when I compile using MSVC10 compiler & more that 8MB when I use GCC compile & these sizes are best cases!.`

As long as we can see any make file. or other settings, it is difficult here to help.

To the above results, it can be seen that it is possible to create a wx application with only 128.000 KB.

dtx02.cpp

```
#include "dtx02.h"

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

dxDialog::dxDialog( wxWindow* parent, wxWindowID id, const wxString& title, const wxPoint& pos, const wxSize& size, long style ) : wxDialog( parent, id, title, pos, size, style )
{
    this->SetSizeHints( wxDefaultSize, wxDefaultSize );

    wxBoxSizer* bSizer2;
    bSizer2 = new wxBoxSizer( wxVERTICAL );

    m_button1 = new wxButton( this, ID_SHOWMESSAGE, wxT("&Show a message"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    bSizer2->Add( m_button1, 0, wxALL, 5 );

    m_button2 = new wxButton( this, wxID_OK, wxT("&Close"), wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    bSizer2->Add( m_button2, 0, wxALL, 5 );

    m_notebook1 = new wxNotebook( this, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, 0 );
    m_panel1 = new wxPanel( m_notebook1, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL );
    m_panel1->SetBackgroundColour( wxSystemSettings::GetColour( wxSYS_COLOUR_BTNFACE ) );

    m_notebook1->AddPage( m_panel1, wxT("a page"), true );
    m_panel2 = new wxPanel( m_notebook1, wxID_ANY, wxDefaultPosition, wxDefaultSize, wxTAB_TRAVERSAL );
    m_notebook1->AddPage( m_panel2, wxT("a page"), false );

    bSizer2->Add( m_notebook1, 1, wxEXPAND | wxALL, 5 );

    this->SetSizer( bSizer2 );
    this->Layout();

    this->Centre( wxBOTH );

    // Connect Events
    this->Connect( wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW, wxCloseEventHandler( dxDialog::OnClosex ) );
    m_button1->Connect( wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler( dxDialog::OnShowMessage ), NULL, this );
    m_button2->Connect( wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler( dxDialog::OnClose ), NULL, this );
}

dxDialog::~dxDialog()
{
    // Disconnect Events
    this->Disconnect( wxEVT_CLOSE_WINDOW, wxCloseEventHandler( dxDialog::OnClosex ) );
    m_button1->Disconnect( wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler( dxDialog::OnShowMessage ), NULL, this );
    m_button2->Disconnect( wxEVT_COMMAND_BUTTON_CLICKED, wxCommandEventHandler( dxDialog::OnClose ), NULL, this );

}
```

dtx02App.cpp

```
#include "dtx02App.h"
#include "dtx02dxDialog.h"

IMPLEMENT_APP(dtx02App)

dtx02App::dtx02App()
{
}

dtx02App::~dtx02App()
{
}

bool dtx02App::OnInit()
{
    dtx02dxDialog* dialog = new dtx02dxDialog( (wxWindow*)NULL );
    dialog ->Show();
    SetTopWindow( dialog );
    return true;
}
```

dtx02dxDialog.cpp

```
#include "dtx02dxDialog.h"

dtx02dxDialog::dtx02dxDialog( wxWindow* parent )
:
dxDialog( parent )
{

}

void dtx02dxDialog::OnClosex( wxCloseEvent& event )
{
    wxTheApp->Exit();
}

void dtx02dxDialog::OnShowMessage( wxCommandEvent& event )
{
      wxMessageBox( wxT("wxFormBuilder Tut") );
}

void dtx02dxDialog::OnClose( wxCommandEvent& event )
{
    wxTheApp->Exit();
}
```